# Javascript array, for every increment create a nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which always has a `length` of `50`, which looks like so:

```
var array = [
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  'item',
  ...
];
```

What I need to do is loop through that array and create a nested array every 5 items, so the end result will be `array` containing 10 nested arrays which contain 5 items each, looking something like:

```
var array = [
  [
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item'
  ],
  [
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item'
  ],
  [
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item'
  ],
  [
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item'
  ],
  ...
];
```

I've tried quite a few things which always ends up in a complete mess of spaghetti loops, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm even open to using jQuery if needs be.

Comment: Post your spaghetti, we're quite the supportive group here.

Comment: Your comment reads like you only want every fifth element in the first array to have a nested array.  Is that right?

Comment: just splice the array. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array = ['item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item'];
var new_arr = [];
while(array.length) new_arr.push(array.splice(0,5));

console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: Ended up going with this, worked a treat, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Just have one for loop.

```
var temp=[], newArray=[];
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    temp.push(array[i]);
    if(temp.length==size){//size in your case = 5
        newArray.push(temp);
        temp=[];
    }
}
```